# how to inherit from typing.NamedTuple and another class correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, multiple-inheritance, namedtuple

There is a class I'm trying to extend, and to save on `self.xxx = xxx` boilerplate code I'm inheriting a `typing.NamedTuple` as well. I managed to make it work, but it looks really weird

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from typing import NamedTuple

class FooBar:
    """
    I come from a third-party module, I'm not a particularly nice class.
    I don't welcome or pass through stray arguments,
    neither do I call super().__init__ at all.
    So ideally I have to be inherited first.
    """

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    def getFooBar(self):
        return 'foo={}, bar={}'.format(self.foo, self.bar)

BazQux = NamedTuple(
    'BazQux',
    [
        ('baz', 'int'),
        ('qux', 'int')
    ],
);

class Quad(FooBar, BazQux):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        args4bazqux = {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k not in ('foo', 'bar')}
        # but I'm not calling FooBar.__new__, is that bad?
        return BazQux.__new__(cls, **args4bazqux)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        args4foobar = {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in ('foo', 'bar')}
        FooBar.__init__(self, **args4foobar)
        # how comes it takes no arguments?
        super(FooBar, self).__init__()

    def getAll(self):
        return '{}, baz={}, qux={}'.format(self.getFooBar(), self.baz, self.qux)

q = Quad(foo=0, bar=1, baz=2, qux=3)
print(q.getAll())
```

Is it okay to do what I'm doing? Is it portable?

Also, that looks fragile, as it looks like relying on how `NamedTuple` works. If the other class behaved similarly I wouldn't be able to inherit it as well. Is there a generic solution that would work with any classes, like e.g. with two different `NamedTuple`s?

Comment: I can understand your hatred. However, I have things to hate as well, boilerplate among them. Do you think there might be another way to reduce it in my situation?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) doesn't support multiple inheritance either. Inheriting from two things that don't support multiple inheritance will most likely result in more code than simply just writing `BazQux` as a regular class with multiple inheritance in mind.

Comment: BTW what is "supporting multiple inheritance"? I found nothing in the docs regarding this, neither for dataclasses, nor for namedtuple. Do classes not support multiple inheritance unless stated otherwise?

Comment: Maybe it would've been more accurate to say "cooperative multiple inheritance". You can of course always inherit from multiple classes, but as you've seen there's no guarantee that something as basic as calling the constructor won't throw an exception. What I meant was basically "write a constructor that accepts `*args, **kwargs` and calls `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`".